# How can I pass a recaptcha v2 from one proxy to another?

Tags: python, proxy, captcha

I am trying to log onto a page under a proxy through an automated selenium script in python. Each time I do so, a captcha (specifically a recaptcha v2) pops up. Is there any way I can generate another captcha under a different proxy using the captcha token from the prompt or something to solve the captcha? And then, would I be able to pass the response code into the original captcha to solve it? I am largely looking for an explanation of how the captcha solving sites generate a captcha from the site key and URL, and how they can extract the response code.

Comment: The purpose of a capture is to make solving it automatically as hard as possible.

Comment: I am not trying to solve it automatically, I am simply trying to scrape the captcha from one site, so I can solve it under a different proxy.